# SQL Email Tabular Format giving Scientific Values instead of fixed decimals

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, html-email, database-mail

I have a query that sends the results to my email in a tabular format. I am using this link as a reference. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2347/send-email-in-a-tabular-format-using-sql-server-database-mail/

I am able to successfully send the email with the data I want, but the values are not the way I want it.

[image]

When I run the query with out using HTML I get the right formatted values.

[image]

What do I need to do in the script that will get me the fixed values and not the scientific notation when implementing a html tabular format?  Any help is most appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE #timetot 

DECLARE @intVar INT 

SET @intVar=0; 

; 
WITH ss 
     AS (SELECT a.rowid, 
                a.employee, 
                Sum(b.value) AS Total 
         FROM   employeetimesheets b 
                RIGHT JOIN employees a 
                        ON a.rowid = b.empid 
         WHERE  b.day >= Dateadd("d", -6, '2015-10-10') 
                AND b.day <= Dateadd("d", -0, '2015-10-10') 
         GROUP  BY a.rowid, 
                   a.employee 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT rowid, 
                employee, 
                @intVar AS Total 
         FROM   employees 
         EXCEPT 
         SELECT empid, 
                employee, 
                @intVar AS Total 
         FROM   employeetimesheets a 
                INNER JOIN employees b 
                        ON a.empid = b.rowid 
         WHERE  a.day >= Dateadd("d", -6, '2015-10-10') 
                AND a.day <= Dateadd("d", -0, '2015-10-10')) 
SELECT * 
INTO   #timetot 
FROM   ss 

DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(max) 

SET @xml = Cast((SELECT [rowid]    AS 'td', 
                        '', 
                        [employee] AS 'td', 
                        '', 
                        [total]    AS 'td', 
                        '' 
                 FROM   #timetot 
                 ORDER  BY rowid 
                 FOR xml path('tr'), elements) AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Employees with Un-finished or Null Timesheets</H3> <table border = 1>  <tr> <th> RowId </th> <th> Employee </th> <th> Total </th> </tr>' 
SET @body = @body + @xml + '</table></body></html>' 

EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name = '***', 
  @body = @body, 
  @body_format ='HTML', 
  @recipients = '****.com', 
  @subject = 'E-mail in Tabular Format';
```

Comment: What datatype is b.value?

Comment: The value type is a float

Comment: There is the problem. You are using an approximate datatype. You should consider using changing your table to numeric instead. You can also cast/convert your value in your query. cast(b.value as numeric(9,2)) or whatever size is reasonable for your data.